# how to send a link to the edit view of a list item from a workflow

Tags: workflow, email

Is it possible to go to the edit view of an sharepoint 2010 list item directly from email? I have a workflow that sends an email to a user to edit a list item. The link -at this time- takes them to the list. I would like for the link to take them to the edit view of that item.
thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, you'd just need to craft a hyperlink to the edit form in the email body.

```
<a href="http://your.domain.com/sites/sitecollection/Lists/Tasks/EditForm.aspx?ID=[Add current item id here]">Edit item</a>.
```

Use the SPD interface to add in a workflow variable for the current item ID or task ID in the URL above where the [] are.

Comment: I've been using this approach, came looking for a solution with relative urls, please look at Webbie4 reply, as your post was selected as answer I think it might be very useful for others to mention it.

Comment: Using relative URLs in an email may lead to unintended consequences, I've seen them try to open wrong sites, using absolute URLs would be preferred.

Answer (score 32):

Use Sharepoint Designer:

In the body of the form "send an e-mail", find 'edit hyperlink' button in the upper right corner of the message.

for field address, click lookup for string or '*fx*'

in Data Source, select “Workflow Context”. 
for field from source, select "Current Item URL".

Now Save, publish and test.

Comment: Nice find! I didn't know about "Workflow Context"->"Current Item URL". Way beter than creating the url by hand (as PirateEric suggest).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't answer the question, which is to link to the **edit** form.

Comment: Ricardo Work Context : Current Item URL didn't work for me. It creates a hyperlink value of "list/listname/12.000" Instead of a URL. Am I missing something?

Comment: Worked in SPO, thanks for this normally had to do the above answer, to copy the direct link for the site and adding the ID in the end, it worked but didn't allow for reusable workflows. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The following solution worked for me:

1. In the body of the WorkFlow email, position yourself where you want the link to go
2. Then click on the `Edit Hyperlink` button in the top right of the window
3. In the address, paste in the URL to your `EditForm` for example:
   `https://domain.sharepoint.com/Lists/mylistname/EditForm.aspx?ID=`
4. Then select the string builder button (...) to open the string builder window.
5. In the string builder window position your cursor at the end of the line (just after ID=) then press the `"Add or Change Lookup"` button.
6. Select `Data Source = "Current Item"` and Field from `source = "ID"`

Then ok that and save and publish.

Comment: Even though this is a good approach, the answer posted by Webbie4 aims for relative links, so wherever you deploy the solution it will work without having to manually go into the workflow and change the link.

Answer (score 5):

I have just found a rather simple, yet brilliant, solution [here](https://sharepointhero.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/sending-mail-using-work-flow-and-%E2%80%9Cencoded-absolute-url-problem/)

Basically, in the hyperlink editor add the following:

```
[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]/../EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Current Item:ID%]
```

Comment: Please don't add the exact same answer to this question, as you did on [this one](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128281/sharepoint-2013-absolute-encoded-url-is-wrong/200651#200651). Instead, try to specify your answer further to make it a better of this specific question. Thank You!

Comment: @BennySkogberg  Having read the guidance here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions?rq=1, I'm going to delete my other answer to the other question as I think this answer is more relevant to this question

Comment: Awesome find!! Up you go.

Comment: This is more portable, since it works even if the list has been renamed and you can tweak the solution slightly if you need to direct someone to the View or New forms.

Answer (score 0):

you just set property in CreatTask

[image]

than after you can access listitemid like below

```
 int i = InvoiceApproverTask.TaskItemId;

string EditItemURL = workflowProperties.Web.Url.ToString() + "/" + workflowProperties.TaskList.RootFolder.Url + "/" + "EditForm.aspx?ID="+i;
```

Hops its helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

The best I have found to get the URL is by using a combination of InfoPath formula and workflow variables

- Create a custom InfoPath form.  In the form, add a field call
  "ItemURL"
- Using an InfoPath rules, set the value of the field to formula: 
            SharePointListURL()
- In SharePoint Designer, create a new workflow and add a workflow variable wfURL
- Set the variable to field [ItemURL]
- Set [ItemURL] = [Variable: wfURL]Item/editifs.aspx?ID=[Current Item: ID]
- In the workflow, set the hyperlink to [Current Item: ItemURL]

The end result will a field containing the url to the edit form "http://YourSiteCollection/YourSubSite/Lists/Item/editifs.aspx?ID=[ItemID]

Works a charm, and it basically dynamic because if the list is moved, or the site collection is changed, the URL changes with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the email add a link with this as the address 
`[%TaskProcess:WebURL%]/[%TaskProcess:ItemURL%]`.

It opens the List Item (Document)

Comment: But not the edit form, right? I think the question at hand is how to create a link to the edit form.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution worked for me.

1. First create a variable called ***URL-Item*** in SharePoint Designer.
   That variable should hold:

   a) link to your sharePoint list 
   Instead of this format:

   > `http://br.com/Mordor/HR/Lists/Schulungsantrag/AllItems.aspx`

   use this one

   > `http://br.com/Mordor/HR/Lists/Schulungsantrag/DispForm.aspx?ID=`

   b) and next to it (in the same row) `Current Item: ID`
2. Create Send an email action and in the email body part create a link based on the variable created earlier (s. the figure below). 
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented the solution to redirect to the edit form from the display form as presented by Andrew here: [Include link to task in task notification email body](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11878/include-link-to-task-in-task-notification-email-body)

Works for both SP10 and SP13 Workflow tasks and solves the relative vs absolute linking problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

The following works with the following criteria

- You are using the default forms, URL unmodified
- You are using Workflow Manager services with SharePoint 2013 workflows

Steps

1. Open your workflow
2. Create a local variable as a string (EditURL as String) [image: Edit URL]
3. Create a Replace Substring in String action
4. Format the action to replace "DispForm.aspx" with "EditForm.aspx" from "Workflow Context: Current Item URL" assigned to the "EditURL" workflow variable. [image: Substring action replacing DispForm with EditForm]
5. The EditURL workflow variable now contains your edit form URL.

Answer (score -1):

In SharePoint 2013 is possible to use this link path:

```
https://your.site.com/sites/sub/subsub/Lists/YourListName/EditForm.aspx?ID=[%Curent Item: ID%]&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fyour%2Esite%2Ecom%2Fsites%2Fsub%2Fsubsub%2FLists%2FYourListName%2FAllItems%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=[%Curent Item: Content Type ID%]
```

Modify to your path and the "AllItems" should be the name of your view. In my case, it worked fine.