# sharepoint 2013 absolute encoded url is wrong

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath, share

In my first sharepoint 2013 workflow, I am sending an email message to the user that submitted the request to let them know it was received.

The message that that is entered into the text of the message is:

Your Standard Request Form [%Current Item:Name%] was successfully submitted.

Use this link to view or modify your report:

[%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]

This email was generated by Sharepoint. Please do not respond to this email.

The text of the email message that the user receives is the following:

Your Standard Request Form 18_.000 was successfully submitted.
Use this link to view or modify your report:
https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/iis/Test/dds/Lists/Standard/18_.000 
This email was generated by Sharepoint. Please do not respond to this email.

The encoded absolute url is incorrect. When you click on the link provided by the url,
you are directed to a location where you can view downloads.

Thus can you tell me what is wrong and/or how to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you mean you need the link open the report not download the report? Maybe you can try change to https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/iis/Test/dds/Lists/Standard/EditForm.aspx?ID=18

Comment: When the user clicks on the link in the email message, I want them to be able to find data they submitted in the link that is provided. Right now I am using the following to get to the url: [%Current Item:Encoded Absolute URL%]. Can you tell me how to code that type of a link you suggested? Also right now when I just click on a list that was created, I get the form called '/Item/displayifs.aspx'. Should I being using a different form that is the default edit. I did modify the form with InfoPath 2013.

Answer (score 2):

I found this resolution for your issue provided in another thread -

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/42362/35743

This link also provides an explanation for the issue and another resolution -

https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/225167